# Schedule task to run 3 times a day for X minutes and if 

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

Below is a sample of the code I was trying, I need to run 1 task in 3 different times for X minutes every day and let's say I have 12,17,20 and it should run for 120 minutes and it is already 12:30:00 so if i open the application it should start the task and it should run for 90 minutes.

**What am I doing wrong here and what do I have to change in order to do the above ?**

```
    // here I receive my config with the hours I need to run my task
    String[] time = Config.SCHEDULE.split(",");
    int runTimeLeft = Config.TIMELEFT;
    for (String hour : time)
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hour));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        long start = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
        ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                startMyTask();
            }
        }, start, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }
```

Comment: @Nishant pardon, bolded question. Java is not really my beach and I am trying to modify the above to fit my needs.

Comment: that's alright. My message was just to point that you were missing the question you wanted to get answered. Take it easy. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly a Java problem...
You need to check if current time (in the calendar) minus current recieved time is more than 0 and less than 2 hours, and if so run the task for "2 hours minus this DIFFERENCE", else what you wrote.

Comment: basicly `runTimeLeft = Config.TIMELEFT - (start * 60 * 1000)` ?

Comment: I don't think I got what you store in Config.TIMELEFT, but I meant something like this: timeFromStart = calendar.getTime - System.current...; period = 2*60*60*100; if (0 < timeFromStart < period) prioud = period - timeFromStart; schedule(......., period); how do i do new lines? :) sorry...